# purpose of using QName

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, qnames

I am very much confused about  the concept behind the QName.

lets take for example (I have taken these examples from http://www.mkyong.com/):

```
        ServerInfoService sis = new ServerInfoService();
        ServerInfo si = sis.getServerInfoPort();
        System.out.println(si.getServerName());
```

And with QName :

```
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/ws/image?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName("http://ws.mkyong.com/", "ImageServerImplService");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        ImageServer imageServer = service.getPort(ImageServer.class);
```

Now my question is :

1) Is there any concepts based on which we have to decide which type of client we can write

2) What is the purpose  or additional benefits in using QName because all I can see here is that it increases complexity as compared to simple client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i know:-

It depends on how you would want to make use of your client to invoke the web service.
The first approach

`ServerInfoService sis = new ServerInfoService();
 ServerInfo si = sis.getServerInfoPort();`

is the plain simple proxy generation approach; where-in you use a tool like wsimport to generate proxies/stubs to your SEI(Service Endpoint Interface)/web-service interfaces and invoke methods on it like any other java method call. Is mostly used in clients where you simply need to invoke methods on the web-service without getting into granular details.

The `QName` or rather the `Service` approach offer finer controls over how the client and webservice communicate. JAXWS 2.0 introduced something called as a `Provider` interface which was an alternative to your SEI which basically let a client communicate at the XML message level and provide a dynamic representation/view of your web-service to the client. More [here](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.1/docs/dispatch.html). The primary use of `Service` API is mostly to create `Dispatch` instances which basically let a client dispatch to a speicific port(method qualified using QName api) using JAXB messages as XML payloads.

Other uses of `Service` api let a client call methods on the webservice asynchronously; provide access to handlers; etc. A good example of using the `Service` and `QName` approach to help you understand further and to relate to what i have said is this link here:- [Dispatching Web Service Calls](http://frankhinkel.blogspot.in/2012/10/dispatching-web-service-calls-async.html).

This being said there is a lot more to know and understand; but hope this gives you a start.

Comment: Thank you very much.